# Wagtail: Getting a list of snippets with counts of related parents

Tags: django, wagtail

Using [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io) I have `ArticlePage`s, each of which can have 0 or more `Author`s, which are Snippets.

I'd like to get a list of `Author`s with the number of `ArticlePage`s they're attached to, but can't work out how. I'm getting confused by [ModelCluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster) I think, as I'd be fine with vanilla Django.

(I'm not even sure if I'm over-complicating this; I don't need the Authors to be orderable on the Articles...)

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

class ArticlePage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('authors', label='Authors'),
    ]

@register_snippet
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
    ]

class ArticleAuthorRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
                'Author',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                related_name='+')

    page = ParentalKey(
                'ArticlePage',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                related_name='authors')

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel('author'),
    ]
```

FWIW, I know I could get a single `Author`'s articles using `article.get_usage()`, which is handy!

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this a day later, I *think* the only issue is having set `related_name` on `ArticleAuthorRelationship`'s `author` property to `'+'` (which [means there's no backwards relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) from `Author` to this model).

If I instead do:

```
class ArticleAuthorRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
                'Author',
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                related_name='articles')  # Changed this to 'articles'
    # etc.
```

Then I can do this quite easily:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from my app.models import Author

authors = Author.objects.annotate(num_articles=Count('articles')).order_by('-num_articles')
```

Then each item in the `authors` QuerySet has a `num_articles` property.

I usually set a `related_name` but this seems less common in the Wagtail docs, and I almost hadn't noticed I'd copied that behaviour here, so this threw me.

If anyone's reading this and can give examples of why/when you'd want to set `related_name` to `'+'`, I'd be interested to know. Thanks.